# CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

When you try to display the contents of a database in `TextView` pops up here this error:

```
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:418)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at ru.zloyel.manager_sutochnoy_arendy_1.ViewContact$LoadContactTask.onPostExecute(ViewContact.java:98)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at ru.zloyel.manager_sutochnoy_arendy_1.ViewContact$LoadContactTask.onPostExecute(ViewContact.java:1)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-27 19:44:59.519: E/AndroidRuntime(5696):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

My DB ContactDBmoy.java

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseErrorHandler;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.provider.BaseColumns;
import android.util.Log;

public class ContactDBmoy extends SQLiteOpenHelper implements BaseColumns {

    // константы для конструктора
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contact_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "contact_table";

    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name_contact";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN = "passport_sn";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "adress";
    public static final String COLUMN_SITE = "site";

    ContactDBmoy cqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;

    private static final String SQL_CREATE_CONTACTS = "CREATE TABLE "
            + TABLE_NAME + " (" + BaseColumns._ID
            + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + COLUMN_NAME
            + " text not null, " + COLUMN_PHONE + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_BIRTHDAY + " integer, " + COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN
            + " text not null, " + COLUMN_ADRESS + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_SITE + " text not null " + ");";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_CONTACTS = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
            + TABLE_NAME;

    public ContactDBmoy(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ContactDBmoy(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
            int version, DatabaseErrorHandler errorHandler) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, errorHandler);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_CONTACTS);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.w(ContactDBmoy.class.getName(), "Обновление базы данных с версии "
                + oldVersion + " до версии " + newVersion
                + ", которое удалит все старые данные");
        // Удаляем предыдущую таблицу при апгрейде
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_CONTACTS);

        // Создаём новый экземпляр таблицы
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Создаёт новый элемент списка. Если создан успешно - возвращается номер
     * строки rowId, иначе -1
     */

    public long createNewContact(String name_contact, String phone,
            String birthday, String passport_sn, String adress, String site) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues initialValues = createContentValues(name_contact, phone,
                birthday, passport_sn, adress, site);

        long row = db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, initialValues);
        db.close();

        return row;

    }

    /**
     * Обновляет список
     */

    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name_contact, String phone,
            String birthday, String passport_sn, String adress, String site) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues updateValues = createContentValues(name_contact, phone,
                birthday, passport_sn, adress, site);

        return db.update(TABLE_NAME, updateValues, _ID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    /**
     * Удаляет элемент списка
     */
    public void deleteContact(long rowId) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID + "=" + rowId, null);
        db.close();
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает курсор со всеми элементами списка
     * 
     * @return курсор с результатами всех записей
     */
    public Cursor getAllContact() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[] { BaseColumns._ID,
                COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_PHONE, COLUMN_BIRTHDAY, COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN,
                COLUMN_ADRESS, COLUMN_SITE }, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    /**
     * Возвращает курсор с указанной записи
     */
    public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor mCursor = db.query(true, TABLE_NAME, new String[] { COLUMN_NAME,
                COLUMN_PHONE, COLUMN_BIRTHDAY, COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN,
                COLUMN_ADRESS, COLUMN_SITE }, _ID + "=" + rowId, null, null,
                null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    /*
     * Создаёт пару ключ-значение и записывает в базу
     */

    private ContentValues createContentValues(String name_contact,
            String phone, String birthday, String passport_sn, String adress,
            String site) {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name_contact);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PHONE, phone);
        cv.put(COLUMN_BIRTHDAY, birthday);
        cv.put(COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN, passport_sn);
        cv.put(COLUMN_ADRESS, adress);
        cv.put(COLUMN_SITE, site);
        return cv;
    }

}
```

ViewContact.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ViewContact extends Activity {
    private long rowID; // имя выбранного контакта
    private TextView nameTV; // отображает имя контакта
    private TextView phoneTV; // номер телефона контакта
    private TextView birthdayTV; // дата рождения контакта
    private TextView passportTV; // паспортные данные контакта
    private TextView adressTV; // адрес прописки контакта
    private TextView siteTV; // адрес прописки контакта

    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name_contact";
    public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
    public static final String COLUMN_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
    public static final String COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN = "passport_sn";
    public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "adress";
    public static final String COLUMN_SITE = "site";

    ContactDBmoy cqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sdb;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.contact_view_moy);

        nameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
        phoneTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phoneTV);
        birthdayTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.birthdayTV);
        passportTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.passportTV);
        adressTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.adressTV);
        siteTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.siteTV);

        // получение ID строки выбранного контакта
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        rowID = extras.getLong(ContactDBmoy._ID);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        // создание нового класса LoadContactTask и вызов его
        new LoadContactTask().execute(rowID);
    }

    // выполняет запрос к базе данных за пределами потока GUI
    private class LoadContactTask extends AsyncTask<Long, Object, Cursor> {
        ContactDBmoy cqh = new ContactDBmoy(ViewContact.this);

        // выполнение доступа к базе данных
        @Override
        protected Cursor doInBackground(Long... params) {
            sdb = cqh.getWritableDatabase();

            // получение курсора, содержащего все данные выбранной записи
            return cqh.getContact(params[0]);
        }

        // использование объекта типа Cursor, возвращаемого методом
        // doInBackground
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Cursor mCursor) {
            super.onPostExecute(mCursor);

            mCursor.moveToFirst(); // перемещение к первому элементу

            // получение индекса столбца для каждого элемента данных

            int nameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
            int phoneIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONE);
            int birthdayIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BIRTHDAY);
            int passportIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN);
            int adressIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ADRESS);
            int siteIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SITE);

            // заполнение компонентов TextViews выбранными данными
            nameTV.setText(mCursor.getString(nameIndex));
            phoneTV.setText(mCursor.getString(phoneIndex));
            birthdayTV.setText(mCursor.getString(birthdayIndex));
            passportTV.setText(mCursor.getString(passportIndex));
            adressTV.setText(mCursor.getString(adressIndex));
            siteTV.setText(mCursor.getString(siteIndex));

            mCursor.close(); // закрытие курсора результата
            sdb.close(); // закрытие подключения к базе данных

        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.view_contact_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.editItem:
            // создание Intent для запуска AddEditContact
            Intent addEditContact = new Intent(this, Contact.class);

            // передача данных выбранного контакта
            addEditContact.putExtra(ContactDBmoy._ID, rowID);
            addEditContact.putExtra("name", nameTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("phone", phoneTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("birthday", birthdayTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("passport_sn", passportTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("adress", adressTV.getText());
            addEditContact.putExtra("site", siteTV.getText());
            startActivity(addEditContact);
            return true;

        case R.id.deleteItem:
            deleteContact(); // удаление отображенного контакта
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    // удаление контакта
    private void deleteContact() {
        // создание нового AlertDialog Builder
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(ViewContact.this);

        builder.setTitle(R.string.confirmTitle);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.confirmMessage);

        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.button_delete,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int button) {
                        final ContactDBmoy cqh = new ContactDBmoy(
                                ViewContact.this);

                        // создание класса AsyncTask, удаляющего контакт
                        // из другого потока, после удаления вызывается finish
                        AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object> deleteTask = new AsyncTask<Long, Object, Object>() {
                            @Override
                            protected Object doInBackground(Long... params) {
                                cqh.deleteContact(params[0]);
                                return null;
                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
                                finish(); // возврат в AddressBook
                            }
                        };

                        // вызов класса AsyncTask для удаления контакта с rowID
                        deleteTask.execute(new Long[] { rowID });
                    }
                });

        builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.button_cancel, null);
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

What is my error?

Comment: Your `Cursor` does not contain any results. That is, the backing query yields an empty result set. If you check the return value of `mCursor.moveToFirst()`, then you'll probably find that it returns `false`. You can't extract any data from a `Cursor` if there are zero results and will need to take that scenario into account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting no values in the cursor, like [MH.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1029225/mh) pointed in the comments. You can change your code to the following to avoid CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor mCursor) {
        super.onPostExecute(mCursor);

        if(mCursor.moveToFirst()){ // перемещение к первому элементу

            // получение индекса столбца для каждого элемента данных

            int nameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
            int phoneIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PHONE);
            int birthdayIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_BIRTHDAY);
            int passportIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PASSPORT_SN);
            int adressIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ADRESS);
            int siteIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_SITE);

            // заполнение компонентов TextViews выбранными данными
            nameTV.setText(mCursor.getString(nameIndex));
            phoneTV.setText(mCursor.getString(phoneIndex));
            birthdayTV.setText(mCursor.getString(birthdayIndex));
            passportTV.setText(mCursor.getString(passportIndex));
            adressTV.setText(mCursor.getString(adressIndex));
            siteTV.setText(mCursor.getString(siteIndex));
        }

        mCursor.close(); // закрытие курсора результата
        sdb.close(); // закрытие подключения к базе данных

    }
```

Hope it helps.