# How to retrieve data from SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-sqlite

I am working on an sqlite database in which I am sure that I have inserted in sqlite correctly.
Now i am fetching data from sqlite using cursor but when I set the data to Texview, my application crashes. Here is my table:
here is my db code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " WHERE ID = 23";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return cursor;
```

Here is my cursor code:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getCheckOutProduct(Id);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            do {
                int proId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                int addressId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"));
                int paymentTypeID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
                int customerID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductID"));
                Log.e("ProductId",String.valueOf(proId));
            }while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
```

Where am I making a mistake?

[image: here is my exception]

Comment: post your logcat.

Comment: i have uploaded snapshot that click on here in my exception

Comment: need to check Cursor.getCount()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22079030/cursorindexoutofboundsexception-index-0-requested-with-a-size-of-0)

Comment: no, this code is different from the original: `while(c.moveToNext()) {...` will work but `do {...` will NOT

Comment: see my updated question. i have changed it. now i am getting exception in do block

Comment: see my answer above - just use `while(c.moveToNext()) {...` and it will work - no need to check `getCount()`, no need to `moveToFirst()` - just one simple `while(c.moveToNext())`

Comment: show your table structure

Comment: You need to move the cursor from index **-1** to the first index (`Index -1 requested...`). Moreover, the query returned no results (`... with a size of 0`)

Answer (score 0):

```
     if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
           cursor.moveToFirst();
                do {
                    int proId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
                    int addressId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"));
                    int paymentTypeID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
                    int customerID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductID"));
                    Log.e("ProductId",String.valueOf(proId));
                }while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
```

Comment: count is also greater than 0

Comment: Then you need to debug the column names

Answer (score -1):

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM " + PRODUCT_TABLE + " where id = 23";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,null);
    return cursor;
```

this is right query i guess

Comment: @ Kishan Singh ,you  need to check row count which return from query

Answer (score -1):

Where are you storing the values retrieved form cursor? For easiness, you can create a model with required attributes and set it one by one, and return a list like this:

```
Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getCheckOutProduct(Id);
List<Model> values = new ArrayList<>();
    if (cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        do {
            int proId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ID"));
            int addressId = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Price"));
            int paymentTypeID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("Quantity"));
            int customerID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProductID"));

            Model model = new Model();
            model.setProdId(prodId);
            //just like above line set other desired values.                
            values.add(model);
            Log.e("ProductId",String.valueOf(proId));
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    return values;
```

Hope this helps to debug the problem.